# Where to add the code for the regular expression to ensure that only numbers are accepted

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation, richtextbox

I am trying to add regular expression to the code below to ensure that only numbers are accepted. The code is very basic it calculates the area of a square and put the result in a RichTextBox.Text 
I am using VB Visual Studio 2012. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
------------------------------------------------------
Public Class SquareArea
    Inherits ShapeArea
    Public Overrides Function Area() As Double
        Return (Me.Lengh ^ 2)
    End Function
End Class

------------------------------------------------------------
Public Class Square

    Private Sub Square_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub ResultButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResultButton.Click
        Dim area = New SquareArea
        area.Lengh = SideTextBox.Text
        ResultRichTextBox.Text = area.Area()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseSquareButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseSquareButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Private Sub SideTextBox_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WidthTextBox.Validating
        'your code here

        If (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(WidthTextBox.Text, "^[0-9]*$")) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.")
            WidthTextBox.Text.Remove(WidthTextBox.Text.Length - 1)
        End If

    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this. But the best would be to use the Validating Event of the SideTextBox textbox.

```
Private Sub SideTextBox_Validating  (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtSideTextBox.Validating
'your code here
End Sub
```

or 
You could also use its KeyPress Event so the user is prompted whenever they enter a non-numeric character.

```
Private Sub SideTextBox_KeyPress (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSideTextBox.KeyPress
'your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use KeyPress, that won't handle the case where the user pastes in invalid input. Validating is fine, but even better would be to use a NumericUpDown control instead of a TextBox.

Comment: @cody based on the qsn he asked, you could use keypress to test if the character entered is numeric...but thanks for your comment, I'll look into ur.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
Private Sub txtValue_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtValue.KeyPress

        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: This code worked but i have to use regular expression

Comment: This code is not working, I am not sure why. Any Help?

Comment: This code is not working, I am not sure why. Any Help                        Private Sub SideTextBox_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WidthTextBox.Validating
        'your code here

        If (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(WidthTextBox.Text, "^[0-9]*$")) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.")
            WidthTextBox.Text.Remove(WidthTextBox.Text.Length - 1)
        End If

    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually write in Visual Basic but you are looking to add RegularExpression to your class as a Class Member (System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace). Regular Expression Pattern shown below will allow only digits. Calling the Match method on regex returns a Match class which you can call Success on for a Boolean result (true/false)

You may have to make slight changes as I don't normally write in VB, but the expression and class are correct

```
'Declare Regular Expression Class, Compile once    
Dim RegularExpression regex As RegularExpression = New RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", RegExOptions.Compile)
    Private Sub Square_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub ResultButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResultButton.Click
        Dim area = New SquareArea
    ' Insert Magic Here
    If regex.Match(SideTextBox.Text).Success=False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry")
        Return
    End If
        area.Lengh = SideTextBox.Text
        ResultRichTe...

    Private Sub CloseSquareButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseSquareButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: You're right, of course. But using regular expressions for this is like using a bazooka to kill a fly. There are better solutions. :-)

Comment: I agree. One of those cases where I'm writing RegEx code atm =) so was first thing that came to mind